# Incomplete or delayed label text in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the text label of a cell set by URL task. But when I first load up the app the label text is not set to the task results until I either scroll the table view or I select the cell itself.

I am assuming my code needs to manually "update" the view of the cell? Here is a task I am using inside of the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
if indexPath.row == self.homeLabels.count - 1 {
        let task1 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url1!) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
                return
            }

            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data)
            parser.delegate = self
            if parser.parse() {
                println(self.results)
                if indexPath.row == 0 { 
                    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = self.parseResults
                }
            }
}
```

I've tried adding a tableView.reloadData() but that seems to not be the correct function.

Comment: You are calling web services in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ?? And you are not preventing anywhere to get same request call again, not a good approach. You should make an array of requests and then call them one by one as soon as you get the response of request you can keep that response to an array (Which is being used for table items) and then reload table.

Comment: @TheTiger To reload the table, reloadData() is used correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not a good way to do this.

First, NSURLSession is an asynchronous networking, that means they run the networking off of the main thread.

Second, you should have a data model, like array to hold these strings from self.parseResults, and handle these requests in viewDidLoad.

Finally, check all the requests done or not. If done, than reload the tableview, feeding all data to UI.

Comment: I've been trying to understand the array-data-model and reload-when-done and still have no clue as to how that would work. Do you know of any examples that do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do all UI updates on the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // Update UI
}
```